# Page generating multiple tables when displaying data

Tags: php, html

I am working on small project where I have to display data from the database, however when doing so, the page displays multiple tables.

For example, you have 2 different records stored in the database (the first record is 1 and the second is 2), whenever I output 1 and 2, instead of displaying 1 and 2 in one table with 1 header, the whole table, header included, duplicates.

I am trying to display all the data in *one* table.

```
<?php 
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    $sqli = "SELECT datum, v, vo, nav FROM  months;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if($row['datum'] AND $row['v'] AND $row['vo'] AND $row['nav']) {

                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Datum</th>";
                echo "<th> Vakantie uren</th>";
                echo "<th> Vakantie uren opgennomen </th>";
                echo "<th> Nieuw aantal vakantie uren</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['datum']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['v']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['vo']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['nav']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";

            }
        }
    }   
?>
```

So far I have tried:

- to put the TH out of the table
- make a new table for them
- put them above the if and while statements

But none of those methods are working.

Comment: First of all get rid of mixing html + php + mysql...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code was that you were also printing the table headers in the while loop. for example if there were 3 rows in the table, it would output them all in three tables.

I changed to code to cater this issue, first print the table html and table headers, then iterate in the loop to print the data, and close the table while outside the while loop. Try this code if it works.

```
  <?php 

                include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
                    $sqli = "SELECT datum, v, vo, nav FROM  months;";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
                    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                      if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                            echo "<table>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<th>Datum</th>";
                                echo "<th> Vakantie uren</th>";
                                echo "<th> Vakantie uren opgennomen </th>";
                                echo "<th> Nieuw aantal vakantie uren</th>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                if($row['datum'] AND $row['v'] AND $row['vo'] AND $row['nav']) {


                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['datum']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['v']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['vo']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['nav']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
                    echo "</table>";
    }   
            ?>
```

Comment: Please provide comments before anyone down votes this answer.

Comment: Farhan Qasim, you did it! My gratitude to you is immeasurable. I can accept an answer in 7 minuts so i'll have to wait before I can give it a green check. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @Dominus no problem sir, any time. :-) and have a great welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: just a quick hit, can I reach you somewhere out? if ever needed.. (I hope you dont mind and I know this isnt the place to ask.)

Comment: i'm also a bit new to stack overflow, but i will be here in this forum if needed. I am not so great at php myself but i would do what i can to help others in need. I guess you can tag me in any question.

Answer (score 0):

while you want to print a table, `table` tag should be outside of the loop statement and repeated section should be in the loop.

```
<?php 

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
$sqli = "SELECT datum, v, vo, nav FROM  months;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Datum</th>";
                echo "<th> Vakantie uren</th>";
                echo "<th> Vakantie uren opgennomen </th>";
                echo "<th> Nieuw aantal vakantie uren</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($row['datum'] AND $row['v'] AND $row['vo'] AND $row['nav']) {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>".$row['datum']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row['v']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row['vo']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$row['nav']."</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              }
        }
    echo "</table>";
}   
?>
```

Comment: same duplicate of my answer.

Comment: it seems we were trying to answer at the same time and I spend some time on indentation and you post it faster. :).

Comment: @zhilevan, same here, and I got a down vote while I was formatting the code!

Answer (score 0):

You get `th` duplicates due to header is in the loop.
You should move table tags `<table></table>` and table row `<tr></tr>` with header `<th></th>`
outside the loop.
First open a `<table>` tag, show the table header `<th>`

```
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Datum</th>";
        echo "<th> Vakantie uren</th>";
        echo "<th> Vakantie uren opgennomen </th>";
        echo "<th> Nieuw aantal vakantie uren</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

And then show the every row results:

```
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['datum']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['v']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['vo']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['nav']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
```

And finaly, at the end close table tag

```
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't echo the table tags inside the `while` loop, move them outside.

```
<?php 

 include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
 $sqli = "SELECT datum, v, vo, nav FROM  months;";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
 $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
     echo "<table>";
     echo "<thead>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<th>Datum</th>";
     echo "<th> Vakantie uren</th>";
     echo "<th> Vakantie uren opgennomen </th>";
     echo "<th> Nieuw aantal vakantie uren</th>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</thead>";
     echo "<tbody>";

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

         if($row['datum'] AND $row['v'] AND $row['vo'] AND $row['nav']) {
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>".$row['datum']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$row['v']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$row['vo']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$row['nav']."</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
        }
    } 
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}   
?>
```

Comment: Well, taking them out of the "while" loop will cause the code to display 0 outputs. to note for @B001, not everyone is a god like u, my apologies.